# How can i show post in django homepage based on post owner

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

i make a blogger website, every user has their own post that the other can't see it. i want to show the user last post in the homepage(index.html).

what i have tried is if the user already had a post it work well, but if the user doesnt have any post yet, when go to homepage it show other user's last post. how to prevent it? what i want is if the user doesnt have any post yet the homepage show some text that tell the user he doesnt have any post yet.

here is my code

index.html

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container jumbotron p-3 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
  <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1 class="display-4 font-italic">{{ post_title }}</h1>
    <p class="lead my-3">{{texts|truncatewords:20}}</p>
    <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#" class="text-white font-weight-bold">Continue reading...</a></p>
    <small><a href="{% url 'blogs:posts' %}" class="text-white ">See all your posts &raquo;</a></small>
    {%else%}
    <h1 class="display-4 font-italic">Welcome To Bogger</h1>
    <p class="lead my-3">This site is used to post your daily stories without having to worry about other people reading them.</p>
    <a class="btn-lg btn-primary" href="{% url 'users:register' %}" role="button">Register &raquo;</a>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    """The Home Page"""
    post = BlogPost.objects.all()
    post_title = post.last()
    texts = post_title.text
    context = {'post_title': post_title, 'texts': texts}
    return render(request, 'blogs/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood is that you want to show the user their own post, but in the homepage view you just showing them the last post created, whoever was the user he will see the last post, you need database relationship, in this [case one to many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) (one user have many posts)

so in post model you need to add something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and in your view:

```
 if request.user.is_authenticated:
     post=Post.objects.filter(user__pk=request.user.id).last()
     # return template with post
 else:
    # for user not authenticated
```

I think this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
def index(request):

    ...

    # query for just the logger in user's posts:
    if request.user.is_authenticated: 
        posts = request.user.posts.all() 
    
    else: 
        posts = []

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `BlogPost` model has `ForeignKey`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class BlogPost(models.Model):
    ...

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Now modify your `index` function somewhat like this

```
def index(request):
    """The Home Page"""
    if request.user.is_authenticated: 
        posts = BlogPost.objects.all().filter(user__pk=request.user.id).last()
        # TO DO: What do want to pass on to the template
    else:
        posts = []
        # TO DO: Handle when posts is empty 
    # TO DO: Return to template

    ...
```